# Click to call a phone with extension from Android phone via the browser

Tags: android, html, hyperlink, phone-number, phone-call

I am trying to mark up a telephone number with an extension in my website, so users browsing the site can click a link to call. There is a requirement that the user should not have to dial the extension. Also, the extension can be dialed either immediately after the phone is answered, or with a pause after the phone is answered.

I have tried different ways of marking it up. Some of these ways work with iPhone but none of them work with Android phones. The Android phone dials only the phone number, it doesn't automatically dial the extension. I have tested these on Android 5, Android 6.0.1 and one other version of Android.

Based on different suggestions given in Stack Overflow and a few other sites, I have tried the following ways of marking up the telephone number:

```html
<a href="tel:+12223334444,12345;isub=12345">222-333-4444</a>

<a href="tel:+12223334444,12345">222-333-4444</a>

<a href="tel:+12223334444;ext=12345">222-333-4444</a>

<a href="tel:+12223334444;p12345">222-333-4444</a>

<a href="tel:+12223334444p12345">222-333-4444</a>

<a href="tel:+12223334444w12345">222-333-4444</a>

<a href="tel:+12223334444;ext=%201*12345">222-333-4444</a>

<a href="tel:+12223334444%2C12345">222-333-4444</a>

<a href="tel:+12223334444%3B%2C12345">222-333-4444</a>
```

The +1 at the beginning of the number can be omitted (if needed) as we don't expect calls from outside the USA.

Any help in getting click to call working with an extension number on Android phones would be greatly appreciated.